# Move top 1000 lines from text file to a new file using Unix shell commands

Tags: unix, shell, copy

I wish to copy the top 1000 lines in a text file containing more than 50 million entries, to another new file, and also delete these lines from the original file.

Is there some way to do the same with a single shell command in Unix?

Comment: @gagneet: What is the high-level task you're trying to accomplish? Are you splitting the file into chunks, or what? There is probably an alternative that avoids rewriting the entire file as these answers all do.

Comment: @Phil my answer doesn't rewrite the entire file

Comment: @Phil: I wish to convert some lines in the original file to another format. For the same, I need to first derive the lines from this BIG file, and then convert and copy them to another file. But parsing through this file is taking a long time and the machine gets hung, as almost 11G of memory is being used.

Comment: You might want to profile with a subset of your file. In particular, using 'time' to test whether sed and other core utils on your system, as well as whatever else you're using to parse your files, are operating on the filesystem or in memory.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
head -1000 input > output && sed -i '1,+999d' input
```

For example:

```
$ cat input 
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ head -3 input > output && sed -i '1,+2d' input
$ cat input 
4
5
6
$ cat output 
1
2
3
```

Comment: @Alex, do you have a file named 'input'?

Comment: I think you mean "cat > input". I still get the same error message:

$ cat > input
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ head -3 input > output && sed -i '1,+2d' input
sed: 1: "input": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: This does not work. Or if it does, it works with a specific version of sed.

Comment: Okay, I'm using FreeBSD, which does not have a GNU version of sed. I've added an answer that includes a test run of sed vs tail that suggests tail is faster. It is, however, only one test. Nonetheless, head/tail/cp/rm seem to have standard implementations across UNIXes and, if faster, may seem preferable to sed.

Answer (score 38):

```
head -1000 file.txt > first100lines.txt
tail --lines=+1001 file.txt > restoffile.txt
```

Comment: Upvoted, until I noticed the "and also delete these lines from the original file" requirement.

Comment: This does not delete lines from the original file.

Comment: Have patience. Removing the first 1000 lines and writing it back out takes a long, long time.

Comment: I only needed to copy the first x number of rows in a file and store them in another. The first line does the job.

Answer (score 11):

Out of curiosity, I found a box with a GNU version of `sed` (v4.1.5) and tested the (uncached) performance of two approaches suggested so far, using an 11M line text file:

```
$ wc -l input
11771722 input

$ time head -1000 input > output; time tail -n +1000 input > input.tmp; time cp input.tmp input; time rm input.tmp

real    0m1.165s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m1.130s

real    0m1.256s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m1.162s

real    0m4.433s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m1.282s

real    0m6.897s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.159s

$ time head -1000 input > output && time sed -i '1,+999d' input

real    0m0.121s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.121s

real    0m26.944s
user    0m0.227s
sys     0m26.624s
```

This is the Linux I was working with:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.18-128.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Jan 26 13:58:24 EST 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For this test, at least, it looks like `sed` is slower than the `tail` approach (27 sec vs  ~14 sec).

Answer (score 7):

This is a one-liner but uses four atomic commands:

```
head -1000 file.txt > newfile.txt; tail +1000 file.txt > file.txt.tmp; cp file.txt.tmp file.txt; rm file.txt.tmp
```

Comment: He wants to *move* the first 1000 lines from one file to another. This deletes all but the first 1000 lines, i.e. is wrong.

Comment: With "more than 50 million entries" that tail will be quite slow.

Comment: Why are you doing "cp file.txt.tmp file.txt; rm file.txt.tmp" instead of "mv file.txt.tmp file.txt"?

Comment: cp and rm are atomic filesystem operations. mv is not.

Answer (score 4):

Perl approach:

```
perl -ne 'if($i<1000) { print; } else { print STDERR;}; $i++;' in 1> in.new 2> out && mv in.new in
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pipe:

```
cat en-tl.100.en | head -10
```